# If $n$ is odd and $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ for all $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$, then $A$ is not invertible. Does the statement hold also when $n$ is even?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have no clue how to do that task. We currently are doing Eigenvalue, Eigenvector and diagonaziable matrices. Do you guys have any ideas how to do this task? I am very sorry for the formating, I cannot get the hang of it.

Translation of the question:
$K$ is a field, $n$ a natural number and $A = (a_{ij}), i,j = 1,...,n \in Mat(n \times n, K)$. Prove this statement: If $n$ is odd and $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ for all $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$, then $A$ is not invertible. Does the statement also apply to the case when $n$ is even?

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In the English, you have $a_{ij} = - a_{ij}$ but, in German, you have $a_{ij} = _{ji}$.  There is a very big difference.  The English version implies that the matrix is zero.

Comment: I edited your question to $\LaTeX$ify it.  Also, in your tanslation, you had changed $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ to $a_{ij} = - a_{ij}$; I changed it back.  May have a few more comments to come.  Cheers!

Comment: Hint: $\det(A)=\det(A^T)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det A$. And, I'm sure this is a dupe, but morning oats should not wait any longer.

Comment: How about the zero matrix?

Comment: The title was mistranslated: *nicht invertierbar* = *not invertible.* The same error crept into the question body.

Comment: [A good match](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2600454/11619) in the sense that the answers there contain everything you need. People may still object if I close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

As Jyrki Lahtonen has noted, the simplest counterexample to an even-$n$ attempt to generalize the theorem is $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$. The reason the theorem only works for odd $n$ is because $A^T=-A$ implies $\det A=\det A^T=(-1)^n \det A$, which implies $\det A=0$ provided $(-1)^n=-1$.

Comment: I think you also need $\text{char}(K) \ne 2$ for your argument to fly, but close enough, ***endorsed!!!***  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis Yeah, someone can probably construct an invertible $3\times 3$ antisymmetric matrix over a characteristic-$2$ field.

Answer (score 0):

Consider  $$ \begin{pmatrix}0&4\\-4&0\end{pmatrix}$$ which is invertible.

Comment: The theorem is about odd dimension and the question is about even dimension as indicated in the title.

Comment: I’m not sure if the statement $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$ applies to the case when $i=j$. It’s not indicated in the question.

Comment: A counterexample in the even case would be an antisymmetric matrix that **is** invertible. Such as $\pmatrix{0&-1\cr1&0\cr}$. Also, what BAI said, in your matrix $a_{11}\neq -a_{11}$.

Comment: Cancelling my downvote because I think the misunderstandings were partly due to errors in translation. I read Geman passably, and I'm now confident that the translation corresponds to the German original. Of course, high rep users are also expected to ask for clarifications when the question does not sound right.